# Html input is not selected on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am adding input via jQuery but can't type anything in it, on click the default blue outline appears and disappears at once. What can be wrong?

**jQuery:**

```
$('#user_description').html('<input type="text" value="" />')
```

**CSS:**

```
#user_description input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 31px;
    background: #403a48;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `append` instead of `html` like this:

```
$('#user_description').append('<input type="text" value="" />')
```

And take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/append/